# formValueSelector always returns undefined

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, redux-form

I have a HOC and a presentation component (one with redux-form), I'm trying to get the input value within the HOC using `formValueSelector` but it always gives me `undefined`

presentation component:

```
interface Props {
  onCreatePayoutPress: () => void
}

const submit = (values: any) => {
  console.tron.log('submitting form', values)
}

class PayoutView extends React.PureComponent<InjectedFormProps<{}, Props> & Props> {
  private renderPayoutInput = (field: any) => (
    <TextInput style={{fontSize: 17}} autoFocus={true} keyboardType={'number-pad'} onEndEditing={this.calculatePayout}/>
  )

  public render() {
    return (
      ...
      <Field name="payoutInput" type="text" component={this.renderPayoutInput}/>
      <Button style={{height:42, marginHorizontal: 15}}
        onPress={this.props.onCreatePayoutPress}>
          {'Pay out now'}
      </Button>
    )
  }
}

export default reduxForm<{}, Props>({
  form: 'PayoutForm'
})(PayoutView)
```

Even with `onPress={handleSubmit(submit)}` reactotron logs indicate the values are empty object {}

HOC:

```
interface Props {
  createPayout: (identityID: string, payoutAmount: number) => void
  payoutAmount: number
}

const identityID = '...'

export default class PayoutScreen extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
public render() {
    return (
      <PayoutView
        onCreatePayoutPress={this._createPayout}
      />
    )
  }

  _createPayout = () => {
    const payoutAmount = this.props.payoutAmount;
    console.tron.log(this.props.payoutAmount)
    // payoutAmount here is always undefined
    this.props.createPayout(identityID, payoutAmount);
  };
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: ReduxState) => {
  const selector = formValueSelector('PayoutForm')
  const payoutAmount = selector(state, 'payoutInput')

  return {
    payoutAmount: selector(state, 'payoutInput')
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ReduxDispatch) => ({
  createPayout: (identityID: string, payoutAmount: number) => dispatch(createPayout(identityID, payoutAmount)),
})

export const PayoutScreen = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(PayoutScreen)
```

reducer:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  ....
  form: formReducer
})
```

Where is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not forwarding the `field.input` prop to the underlying `<TextInput>`.

See for example [here](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/) how the `renderField` has `<input {...input}`.

In that way you can 'connect' your text input with the actual `Field`